# Android AlertDialog: window leaked error

Tags: android

This error is showing for alert.show() line of code .In click interface of dialog, starting new activity like this
 startActivity(new Intent(LayoutActivity.this, MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));

Tried with closing of alert.dismiss() in onPause() and onStop() and onDestroy() still getting same error

Comment: Stack trace can help people to identify your problem better.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. And what I've found out is that it will be enough to `cancel` the alert dialog in `onStop()`. Try this peace of code in `onStop()`: 
`if(dialog != null)
    dialog.cancel();`

Answer (score 1):

that is android's typical problem.

the goal to solve the problem is, show or hide dialog between activity's on Resume() and onPause()

like this

```
boolean isShown = false;
public void onResume()
{
   isShown = true;
   ...
}

public void onPause()
{
   isShown = false;
   ...
}

public void showDialog()
{
   if(isShown)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) it will close all Acitivties opened before.
If you have pretend the activity's theme to be a dialog, just use it as an Activity. If there is an AlertDialog Object, then call alert.dismiss().

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity where this dialog should be seen is not active , or maybe in manifest you set a property **noHistory** of current activity to **true**